# OpenAPI: TypeLoadException, could not find type in dll file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, annotations, openapi

I have this error while generating the OpenAPI documentation for my project in Azure Devops pipeline.
Since the `Domain.TrackerVersion` is located in another project in the same solution, how can I add it to myproject.dll so that it won't complain about not finding the object in the XML?

This is the exception I got :

> POST /api/tracker/updateorcreate || ExceptionType: TypeLoadException || Message: Type "Domain.TrackerVersion" could not be found. Ensure that it exists in one of the following assemblies: myproject.dll Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Comment: @Dijkgraaf yes, I am using C# and Visual Studio.

Comment: You would probably be better of adding c# and visual studio as tags, and remove some that are less relevant to the problem.  That will increase your chances of getting an answer.  But usually you would need to reference either the other project or if it is a reference in the other project, just add a reference directly.